# Is there a trackpad tap visualizer

Tags: osx

Regarding Better Touch Tool: Sometimes My favorite gesture doesn't work, (a double 4 finger tap). I guess it's probably due to a lack of sync between all of the 4 fingers tapping at the same point in time. Two question regarding the matter:

Is there a trackpad tap visualizer similar to the"live preview" option only that always stays on screen so that I can diagnose what happens when I miss my gesture?
Is there a way to maybe widen the time for all 4 fingers to perform the tap, such that even when they are not all in perfect sync my gesture will come through?

Comment: try https://github.com/jnordberg/FingerMgmt